# What does TRANSFER stand for in VPS spedifications?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, webserver, hosting, vps

I am planning to deploy my rails app on Linode VPS. The VPS specification has a column named Transfer. Transfer: 5 TB. What does this stand for and what does it do and how is it relevant for my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means the amount of data that can be downloaded (or transferred) from your VPS.

It's hard to estimate how much transfer you might use as it entirely depends on what kind of app you're serving and how many users you will have.

I wouldn't worry about it unless you're serving large files such as video, in which case you'd probably want to store those elsewhere.